# Passing Strings in methods

Tags: java, string, methods

I can't figure out how to pass the Strings need to the method below.

stringToFile(); and 
readingStringFromFile();

I know I need to pass the Strings in the main method but I can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);//allow for use of keyboard input

            mask(keyboard);

            printingString();

            fileName(keyboard);

            stringToFile();

            readingStringFromFile();



}
public static int mask(Scanner keyboard){
    int holder;//creats a temp int
    System.out.print("Enter the encryption mask: ");//asks fro encrytipon
    holder = keyboard.nextInt();//userinput to holder
    keyboard.nextLine();//consumption 
    return holder;//returns encryption mask

}

public static void fileName(Scanner keyboard){
    String fileName ="a";
    System.out.print("\nEnter a file name without extensions: ");
    fileName = keyboard.next();//userinput to fileName
    String completeFileName = fileName + ".txt";
}

public static void printingString(){
    System.out.println("Original random character string:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)//loop to obtain 50 random characters
    {
      char randomChar = (char) ((Math.random()*255)+32);
      System.out.print((randomChar));
    }
}

public static void stringToFile(String completeFileName, String printingString)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
   System.out.println("Saving Original random character string..."); 
   File myFile = new File (completeFileName);
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (myFile);

    PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter (myFile);
    fileWriter.println(printingString);
    fileWriter.close();
}

public static void readingStringFromFile(String completeFileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Original random character string from the file");
    File myFile = new File (completeFileName);
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (myFile);

    String lineFromFile = fileReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(lineFromFile);
}
```

Comment: Your method has parameters and you will need to use them, i.e, `myMethod(myParameter)` where myParameter is a String. The best answer though for this question though is for you to study a basic Java tutorial on how to call methods. You won't regret doing this, and it will help you with your future programming projects greatly.

Comment: When you call a method in an Object that method does work for you based in input (parameters) and returns something to you.  For example, your "fileName" method looks like you want it to return the String that is the file name when called.  Change to public static String fileName(xxx)  and return completeFileName    .. look at handling the rest of the methods in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

In your main method you should get the input -

```
    System.out.println("Enter file name : ");
    String completeFileName = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println("Enter string : ");
    String printingString = keyboard.next();

    stringToFile(completeFileName, printingString);
```